# Where does input in Python3 write its output to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#input) says

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline.

But I got the following with Python 3.6.5 on Mac, which seems to output to `stderr`.

```
~/tmp λ cat foo.py
foo = input('input a word:')
print(foo)
~/tmp λ python foo.py 2>bar
hello
hello
~/tmp λ cat bar
input a word:⏎
```

Comment: It looks like the prompt is indeed written to stdout if Python writes it - but in cases where GNU readline is available and suitable for use, the entire job is handed off to it, including the prompt, so the behavior is no longer under Python's control.

Comment: I'd consider this a documentation bug. The `readline` module at least hints at this in its own documentation: "Settings made using this module affect the behaviour of both the interpreter’s interactive prompt and the prompts offered by the built-in input() function.", but the documentation for `input()` should mention that it doesn't unconditionally use standard output for the prompt.